# Bibiliography included in ToC but wrong hyperref linking

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref

I included my bibliography in the tableofcontents as follows (documentclass report):

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{report}
```

This generates the correct output, with the correct page number (41) in the toc.
However, clicking References will take me to the page preceding (40) the page with the references (41).
How can I modify this to take me straight to page 41?
Thanks!

Comment: It should be mentioned that the solution depends a bit on the used document class. For the standard classes »[tocbibind](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind)« is the way to go (as you found out yourself). Classes like »[memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)« or those from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« have built-in mechanisms.

Comment: Go to the tex contents where page 41 corresponds to, then find the section/subsection name you were clicking. Put a \clearpage right before that section name. This is what I would do in such situation.

Comment: `\phantomsection` should go *before* `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by using:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
```

and including the bibliography like this:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{report}
```